# Change post status to draft (on button click - front-end) with wp_update_post()

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm adding a button via shortcode into my post on front-end. On click, this button should change the current post status to 'draft'.

Changing to 'draft' seems to work, but it happens as soon as the post is loaded, not on the button click. Where am I going wrong?

Here is my code:

```
function post_to_draft_button_shortcode() {
    global $post, $current_user;
   
    $post_id = get_queried_object_id();
   
    if ( $post->post_author == $current_user->ID ) {
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <div class="button-draft">
        <a onclick="return confirm('Change this post to draft, sure?')" href="<?php echo wp_update_post(array('ID' => $post_id, 'post_status'  =>  'draft')) ?>">Save as draft</a>
    </div>
    <?php
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    }
    return $output;
   
}
add_shortcode( 'post-to-draft', 'post_to_draft_button_shortcode' );
```

Comment: The href must contain the URL doing the command, not the command itself.

Comment: Would you be able to post an example of the complete href Markus?

Comment: You need to use ajax to make it update the status of the post without refreshing the page. You don't have any jquery/ajax in this function, therefore it won't happen until the page is reloaded.